# What is the best way to permanently mark a record as read-only?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have an Access 2003 app that connects to a SQL Server 2000 box.

I have a table in which I need to lock down a record along with all related records in different tables. By "lock down", I mean mark them as read-only so that no clients can edit those records unless an admin unlocks them.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by 'lock down'?  Permanently prevent changes to it?  Or prevent anyone else from changing during a short period of time while you're doing an operation on it?

Comment: More of a permanent lock. The end user should not be able to edit the records once locked. However, there needs to be a way for an admin to unlock it.

Currently, I have a hidden bit field in my main table that gets set when the record is locked, but I'm having trouble with determining the best way to lock down the related records.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear that you mean a permanent lock.  Some people reading this would have assumed you meant a row-level temporary lock.  I hope this helps you get better answers.

Comment: Is the "master" record in Access, or SQL Server?  Trigger-based solutions will be more difficult if the master record is in ms access.

Comment: All the records reside in Access.

Would an Access solution where I lock my forms be better?

Comment: These are native Access tables and not links to SQL Server?

Comment: I apologize. All the data does in fact reside on the SQL Server. There are no Access local tables.

Comment: Are you using Access as the front end to SQL Server?

Comment: Oh, never mind! I can't seem to read the original post! :)

Answer (score 3):

More than likely there isn't an "elegant" way of doing this at the database level.  But there are a few routes you could do.

1. Add a "locked" bit field to each table, and when "locking" the parent cascade that value.
2. In conjunction with #1 add a trigger on update and delete, if the flag is set, you can cancel the update or delete.

That is about the only real easy way to enforce it at the db level that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in SQL Server, I would use the SQL Server security if possible first.  We typically would not allow any access to tables and then control it through SPs.  SPs can have more complex logic to determine whether a particular operation should go through.

If that's not an option, you can always use triggers, check the rows and deny an update or delete that way.

There's a ton of ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option to throw out there:

- Add a last_updated column to your
  table, which is updated by the update
  trigger
- Create a table, Locked_Widgets (or whatever) which is simply the PK of your base table and the last_updated column and the whole set of columns make up the PK in Locked_Widgets
- Put a non-cascading foreign key from the base table to Locked_Widgets

If anyone tries to update the row the trigger will try to update the last_updated column and the foreign key constraint will cause the update to fail.